# Weight constrains in TensorFlow Neural Networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm training Neural Networks for classification using TensorFlow/Keras, and I would like the weights in the output layer to have the following property:

Suppose the weight or kernel matrix is a `3 by 4 matrix W`, and its elements are `W_ij`

I would like **for each column j, there is one and only one `nonzero W_ij`, and `W_ij = 1`.**

What would be a good way to implement this requirement?

One possible solution I can think of is to put the following constraints:

`W_1j + W_2j + W_3j = 1 for all j = 1,2,3,4`

and

`W_ij * (1-W_ij) = 0, for all i, j`

How do I implement these constraints? Or is there any better way to set this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to control the weight???? If you try to enforce that type of constraint to the weight, your NN will probably never learn anything.

It seems to me that you just want a softmax layer in the output.

A softmax would have exactly what you are saying. Let's supposed you are classifying cats, dogs, birds. If you use a softmax in the output, you will get always a tensor where only one element is 1 ( the most likely class)
example

```
[1,0,0] #cat
[0,1,0] #dog
[0,0,1] # bird
```